# Вычитание времени не работает как надо

Tags: mysql, база-данных, datetime

В программе мне нужно было поставить ограничение на просматриваемое время и я сделал все через Mysql запрос. В чем может быть проблема?

```
SELECT * FROM  ot  where  Date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) - Date(Time) <5  ;
```

Все работало но как наступило 01.02.2022 ,стало выводить только сегодняшнюю дату

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: Ошибку вообще не выдает,просто не вычитает 5 дней ,а выводит только сегодняшнюю дату. Хотелось бы  что бы он выводил записи начиная с сегодняшний даты и минус 5 дней .

Comment: [отсюда можно подобрать дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+datediff)

Comment: Искал похожего ничего нет

Comment: Что содержится в Time?

Comment: PS. Всегда забавно, когда в заголовках пишут, что что-то "работает не как надо", когда надо писать "не могу правильно написать код". Работает как раз как надо, как написано, так и работает.

Answer (score 0):

Содаём базу:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (
  `id` int,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `times` (`id`,`time`) VALUES
  (1,current_timestamp - interval 10 day),
  (2,current_timestamp - interval 3 day),
  (3,current_timestamp - interval 4 day),
  (4,current_timestamp - interval 1 day),
  (5,current_timestamp),
  (6,current_timestamp + interval 1 day)
```

Делаем запрос:

```
select * from times where `time` > current_timestamp - interval 5 day
```

Получаем ответ:

| id | time |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-01-29T11:13:16Z |
| 3 | 2022-01-28T11:13:16Z |
| 4 | 2022-01-31T11:13:16Z |
| 5 | 2022-02-01T11:13:16Z |
| 6 | 2022-02-02T11:13:16Z |

Comment: Большое спасибо догнал

Comment: @Vleron если помогло, отметьте ответ верным.